# What format is "1.34.128.0/113'?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip-address

I know of two format that use similar notation, Classless Inter Domain Routing (CIDR) and Variable Length Subnet Mask (VLSM). However the numbers after the `/` is usually less than 32. However in this case it goes up to 120.

Here are some more output from a IP geolocation script I am using. Is this a valid format? According to the code https://github.com/maxmind/getting-started-with-mmdb/blob/57566b3adfd7e89a6510bf743be1577fcbf3a5dc/examples/03-iterate-search-tree.pl#L22 the format is ip/mask_length.

`1.0.0.0/120
1.0.1.0/120
1.0.2.0/119
1.0.4.0/118
1.0.8.0/117
1.0.16.0/116
1.0.32.0/115
1.0.64.0/114
1.0.128.0/113
1.1.0.0/120
1.1.1.0/120
1.1.2.0/119
1.1.4.0/118
1.1.8.0/117
1.1.16.0/116
1.1.32.0/115
1.1.64.0/114
1.1.128.0/113
1.2.0.0/119
1.2.2.0/120`

Comment: Your list is nonsense. The stub you linked expects an integer (32bit number) as input and generates an IPv4 dot-quad ascii string. IPv4 addresses with a prefix length greater than 32 are invalid.

Comment: Thanks. My networking background is very limited. So thanks for confirming my suspension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `/` value indicates the length of the subnet prefix and IPv4 uses 32 bits in total, that value can only be 0 through 32. `/0` is especially used for the default route `0.0.0.0/0` (=match anything) and `/32` is sometimes used to indicate an end node.

I've seen non-standard and ambiguous notations like "10.0.0.0/63" to indicate `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.63` - what should be `10.0.0.0/26` - but your list doesn't make any sense.